# Besides Strikeforce:Morituri, what was the second property Marvel was developing with Scifi Channel in 2002 as TV series?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, tv

In 2002, [Variety reported the following](https://www.google.com/amp/s/variety.com/2002/scene/markets-festivals/sci-fi-setting-its-sights-high-1117877626/amp/):

> The cabler, along with Universal Television Group sibling Reveille, has pacted with Marvel Studios to translate comicbook “Strikeforce: Morituri” into a live-action drama series. “A Thousand Days” is likely to debut as a series on Sci Fi in 2003. **Project is one of two small-screen adaptations on which Marvel, Sci Fi and Reveille, a joint venture between UTG and Ben Silverman, are looking to collaborate.**

Besides the aborted Strikeforce: Morituri project, does anyone know what the second “of two small-screen adaptations on which Marvel, Sci Fi and Reveille, a joint venture between UTG and Ben Silverman” being developed as of 2002 was?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Legion of Monsters](https://comic-books-in-the-media.fandom.com/wiki/MARVEL_COMICS:_Legion_of_Monsters_(Proposed_Brother_Voodoo_movie))*, a Brother Voodoo film.

> In 2003, the Sci Fi Channel announced it was developing a live-action TV movie and backdoor pilot Brother Voodoo, based on the character. Hans Rodionoff was announced to write the screenplay, set in New Orleans, of this Reveille Productions and Marvel Studios co-production executive produced by Reveille head Ben Silverman and Marvel Studios' Avi Arad and Rick Ungar.

Mentioned in [this article](https://www.c21media.net/news/reveille-and-sci-fi-team-up-on-marvel-duo/) alongside *1000 Days*, the Morituri adaptation:

> Sci-Fi Channel has closed a deal with Universal Television Group sibling Reveille to develop small-screen adaptations of Brother Voodoo and 1000 Days, marking the first joint-venture between the sister companies.
>
> Both projects will be executive produced by Reveille head Silverman, Marvel Studios ceo Avi Arad and Rick Ungar, president of Marvel Characters Group.
>
> Brother Voodoo, a two-hour movie/back-door pilot, will be a live-action drama centring on the adventures of psychologist and voodoo priest. Hans Rodionoff (Clive Barker’s Saint Sinner) is attached as the writer.
>
> Marvel Comics’ Strikeforce: Morituri will be translated into a live-action two-hour back-door pilot movie called 1000 Days, adapted by scribes Matt Holloway and Art Marcum. Set in the near future, the film follows a group of soldiers who gain enhanced abilities.

Comment: That would have been interesting series. Thanks!